# Capturing loading time when a tag is refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we capture loading time when a table is refreshed with new data. when i click on row,the whole table refresh  but not the entire webpage

I checked in my web inspection on network ,
name asyncstatus?qhandles= 1234782  is taking about 6000ms

i have tried

```
   var timerStart = Date.now();
           $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log("Time until DOMready: ", Date.now()-timerStart);
            });
           $(window).load(function() {
                 console.log("Time until everything loaded: ", Date.now()-timerStart);
          });

but this is returning 0 but it should return 6000ms instead
```

is there a possibility we could capture this?

Comment: `milliseconds` ms are not exactly as actual `seconds` in time. there is always a little difference.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping , great but is there away we could capture the xhr timing or there is no function for this ?

Comment: There is not actual function for this. The only way could be check the when you do the ajax request. Store the click time and `minus` the time on success or failure or of ajax request

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, i am working on cross platform to customize a website and i dont have direct access to their ajax url. but thanks

Comment: `console.time('testTime'); /* do stuff */ console.timeEnd('testTime');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");

function mockCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      target.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
      resolve()
    }, 2000);
  })
}

function refresh() {
  mockCall();
  //start time/performance.now with on click
  console.time("console.time");
  var start = window.performance.now();

  //something you know will always change must be stored
  const value = target.textContent;

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    //check if change has occured; 
    if(value !== target.textContent){
      //end time/performance.now after change
      var end = window.performance.now();
      var time = end - start;
      console.timeEnd("console.time"); 
      console.log("performance.now", time);
      //clear interval
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<div id="target">100</div>
<button onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: Yes, what i meant is DOM renderer time. how can we capture the timing when dom is fully loaded on webpage. is there another approach instead of using asyn function as the current webpage that i am working on does not support this function

Comment: You would have to create a set interval that constantly checks your table's text for differences; when it finds a difference it clears the interval and finishes wrapping window.performance.now (or console.timeEnd if value doesn't need to be stored). Why does the webpage not support async/await?

Comment: We dont have direct access to their script as we are working on customizing e.g(tableu web) dashboard on top of their web page. and their js script does not support the newer version es5 - 6 so im looking at different approach .

Comment: ah, so it is their script making the ajax call?

Comment: Yes correct, since we dont have direct access to their ajax call, its quite tricky. i have came out with multiple solutions, using settimeout, intervals , ajaxComplete statement but in terms of performances . its not in production standard and its inconsistent as the dom rendering time will vary.

Comment: I will look into your approach that has been advised. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to better reflect your situation